# Using \author and \thanks for authors with common affiliation latex authors affiliation

Tags: titles, author, affiliation

I have two authors with the same affiliation. I would like to use the same code, but the problem is that the affiliation appears twice. I want it to be one time, as you can see in the figure below, where the authors with the same affiliation appear twice.

\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{tsp}

```
\author{ABCD*{\thanks{School of Computer Science and Technology}},{XYZ \thanks{School of Computer Science and Technology}
```

[image]

journal tamplet

```
\title{Your Paper Title Goes Here and Capitalize Each Letter}
\author{
  First-name Surname{\thanks{First author's affiliation, Address, City and Postcode, Country.}}\
  and Second Author\thanks{Second author's affiliation, Address, City and Postcode, Country.
  \vskip 0.15cm
  \centerline{\textsuperscript{*}Corresponding Author: Author's Name. Email: author@institute.xxx.}
  \vskip 0.15cm
  \centerline{Received: XXXX; Accepted: XXXX.}}$^{\bm ,*}$
}
```

Comment: I changed the tags, why did you tag as [tag:color] ? Author formatting is defined by the document class about which you have given no information.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{tsp}

Comment: put an example and a link to the class in your question. there is no tsp.cls in texlive

Comment: The problem is that I have two authors with the same affiliation. I want it to appear once in the PDF, but the affiliation is repeated. Manuscripts Template for CMES https://www.techscience.com/ueditor/files/TSP_LaTex_Source.rar